# Growing the text segment vs. growing the data segment

Tags: c, embedded-linux

When given the choice to either grow the text segment or the data segment, what set of criteria can determine the choice?

I'm not aware of the differences and impact at either compile- or execution-time given different configurations (dynamically/statically linked, PIC, non-PIC, etc.). So what I'm asking is what the trade-offs involved are.

More concrete: It grows at compile-time through use of a static char array, basically making it either const or not, and constness apparently decides whether it ends up in text or not. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code-segment is read-only, demand-loaded (it can be paged directly from disk) and can be shared.

In contrast, the data-segment is writable (backed by paging-file or RAM) and therefore not shared.

Thus, if you have the choice between growing either one, prefer a smaller data-segment, as the same amount of space in the data-segment in general consumes more resources, even if your program does not run multiple times simultaneously.

There's an additional benefit to marking everything you can `const`:
A failure to respect the fact that the data should not change is more likely to be caught by the compiler, and if not later by the runtime (memory-protection), instead of silently corrupting your state.